# Filter and Sort Symbols - Returning "Character(0)"?

Tags: r, filter, character

I am new to R (and programming in general). I am trying to follow this example:

```
filter_symbols <-function(symbols){
symbols <-toupper(symbols)
valid <-regexpr("^[A-Z]{2,4}$", symbols)
return(sort(symbols[valid == 1))
}
```

I understand this is supposed to covert all the symbols to upper case and return only the symbols with 2-4 letters. But it returns

Character(0)

What does it mean? Why is it happening?

Comment: help us more with letting us know what `symbols` are. a better view of your data and expected output

Comment: Wow this is quick response. The symbols are: "MOT", "cvx", "123", "Gog2", "XLe".  The return is supposed to be "MOT" "CVX" "XLE"

Comment: so basically, you want to filter out words that contain numerics and then convert it to uppercase?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the vector to upper case (`toupper`) and `grep` for only upper case letters from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the strings.

```
grep("^[A-Z]{2,4}$", toupper(v1), value = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( "MOT", "cvx", "123", "Gog2", "XLe")
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked! Which part about it limits the length to 2-4 letters?

Comment: @Gwen Changed the code.  Sorry missed that part earlier